# What is the correct term for _ in a type hint?

Tags: rust, terminology, type-theory

In type hints in Rust it is possible to use partial types in annotations like this:

```
let myvec: Vec<_> = vec![1, 2, 3];
```

What is the correct terminology for the underscore in the partial type annotation? I'm interested in both the Rust terminology as well as more academic type theory terminology.

Comment: @erip in Rust this is not an existential type. It's just asking the compiler to infer the actual type looking at the local scope, but it's generally equivalent to fully typing the one specific type that can go in that _ (which is why they sometimes call it a "placeholder").

Comment: @erip Existential quantification means that some of a type's constructors  depend on type parameters which are not parameters of the type itself. In Rust, this is more akin to a trait object, which has a hidden type parameter - the concrete implementation of the trait. The `_` here does not mean an existential type, it just means that you have omitted the type parameter because the compiler can infer it. I am not very familiar with Scala, but if the Scala "existential type" has the same semantics then it is incorrectly named.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some digging it seems that `Vec<_>` is consistently called a partial type (so in `let x: Vec<_>` we have a partial type annotation, while `Fn(String) -> _` would be a partial type signature) but the `_` in this context is varyingly called either a type wildcard or a type placeholder, and `_` in the type grammar can be read as the token for "infer this type" (at the time of the PR mentioned below, `TyInfer` internally in the compiler).

Some interesting reading:

- [Partial type signatures in Haskell](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/PartialTypeSignatures)
- [The pull request which added `_` to the Rust type grammar](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/12764)
- [Intermingled parameter lists - Niko Matsakis' blog post](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2013/10/29/intermingled-parameter-lists/) in which he proposes to "Introduce `_` as a notation for an unspecified lifetime or type"

Interesting detail from the PR:

```
let x: _ = 5;
let x    = 5;
```

The two lines above are equivalent, and both parsed as variable `x` with type `TyInfer`.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to find a [piece of official documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#match-expressions) where the underscore is named in the context of patterns, but I doubt it's a "strict" name:

> Patterns consist of some combination of literals, destructured arrays or enum constructors, structs and tuples, variable binding specifications, wildcards (..), and **placeholders (_)**.

[The Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/book/first-edition/syntax-index.html#operators-and-symbols) provides the following description in the glossary:

> **_: "ignored" pattern binding** (see [Patterns (Ignoring bindings)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/book/first-edition/patterns.html#ignoring-bindings)). Also used to make integer-literals readable (see [Reference (Integer literals)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/tokens.html#integer-literals)).

I was not able to find a definition pointing *specifically* to partial type annotations, but I think "placeholder" (or "type placeholder", depending on the context) would not be ambiguous.

Comment: Note that the underscore used in pattern matching, the ignored pattern, is a different underscore. Remember that you can only match on variants of a single type. This underscore is on the type level, which is why it would be useful with terminology that disambiguates the two. Not sure if there is any terminology to find though.

Answer (score 2):

In the compiler, it seems to be called **`Infer`** (in [`syntax::ast`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.18.0/src/libsyntax/ast.rs#L1359), [`rustc::hir`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.18.0/src/librustc/hir/mod.rs#L1353), and [`rustc::ty`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.18.0/src/librustc/ty/sty.rs#L169))

I think this naming is somewhat reasonable, because these `_`s are replaced with fresh **(type) inference variables** before doing Hindley-Milner-like type inference.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the grammar refers to it as an "inferred type". Per [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/inferred.html):

> **Inferred type**
>
> Syntax:
>
> ```
> InferredType : _
> ```
>
> The inferred type asks the compiler to infer the type if possible based on the surrounding information available. It cannot be used in item signatures. It is often used in generic arguments:
>
> ```
> let x: Vec<_> = (0..10).collect();
> ```